# How to create a "Loading" pop up in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the 'importrange' function in a 2 way setup between 2 sheets to hide proprietary formulas which takes a few seconds to update results to the current sheet.  What I would like to do is have a "Please wait while loading..." box pop up for X amount of seconds when user information in input cell.  I've seen some examples for pop ups but not sure how to do it when a cell is updated.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the javascript timer.  It will display a modeless dialog for 5 seconds and the go away.  Of course you can put whatever animation on there that you like.  And I included the dispStatus function which I use almost all of the time.  It's probably not the fanciest way to do it.  But it works.

```
 function timer_test()
{
dispStatus('Loading.....','<script>var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,5000);function myTimer() { google.script.host.close();}</script>',200,200)
}

function dispStatus(title,html,width,height)
{
// Display a modeless dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 250;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}
```

Comment: You guys are awesome Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use toasts in spreadsheets:

[Spreadsheet Toast](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String,String,Number))

```
 // Show a 3-second popup with the title "Status" and the message "Task started".
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Task started', 'Status', 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for this example!!

Comment: Good idea.  I forgot about the toast.  Thanks for reminding.